# React Beginner - Trouble understanding useContext for dark mode

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, darkmode

I'm completing an online program to learn ReactJS. After going over useState we are now learning useContext. Below I'll go over my current understanding of how useContext works, and where I'm facing trouble.

[The goal is a simple page with a light/dark mode switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHMLH.png)

What I currently understand as the "steps" to using useContext:

1. Import and initialize createContext
2. Wrap child components with Provider
3. Import useContext hook from React so we can use the Context in child components
4. Access the user Context in desired component(s)

**But I'm facing an issue with understanding the code block below**

This is the solution to a file named ThemeContext.js.

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const ThemeContext = createContext(undefined);

export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("light");

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider
      value={{
        theme,
        toggleTheme: () => setTheme(theme === "light" ? "dark" : "light"),
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useTheme = () => useContext(ThemeContext);
```

This is the solution to App.js.

```
import "./App.css";
import { ThemeProvider, useTheme } from "./ThemeContext";
import Switch from "./Switch";

const Title = ({ children }) => {
  const { theme } = useTheme();
  return (
    <h2
      style={{
        color: theme === "light" ? "black" : "white",
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </h2>
  );
};

const Paragraph = ({ children }) => {
  const { theme } = useTheme();
  return (
    <p
      style={{
        color: theme === "light" ? "black" : "white",
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </p>
  );
};

const Content = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Paragraph>
        We are a pizza loving family. And for years, I searched and searched and
        searched for the perfect pizza dough recipe. I tried dozens, or more.
        And while some were good, none of them were that recipe that would
        make me stop trying all of the others.
      </Paragraph>
    </div>
  );
};

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header>
      <Title>Little Lemon </Title>
      <Switch />
    </header>
  );
};

const Page = () => {
  return (
    <div className="Page">
      <Title>When it comes to dough</Title>
      <Content />
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const { theme } = useTheme();
  return (
    <div
      className="App"
      style={{
        backgroundColor: theme === "light" ? "white" : "black",
      }}
    >
      <Header />
      <Page />
    </div>
  );
}

function Root() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <App />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default Root;
```

Finally, this is the solution to index.js

```
import "./Styles.css";
import { useTheme } from "../ThemeContext";

const Switch = () => {
  const { theme, toggleTheme } = useTheme();
  return (
    <label className="switch">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={theme === "light"}
        onChange={toggleTheme}
      />
      <span className="slider round" />
    </label>
  );
};

export default Switch;
```

**My questions begin here**

1. Instead of directly wrapping children with Provider, they instead create ThemeProvider that *then* returns ThemeContext.Provider. Why is this? and why is { children } necessary as seen in App.js along with the return ThemeContext return statement?

This exercise goes beyond what I believe was taught in the lesson, so I could have some holes to fill in my knowledge as far as using { children } along with the use of ThemeProvider. Normally it's demonstrated as <ThemeContext.Provider> wrapping children on the inside. In App it looks like they don't do this, but it's done in the Root, and maybe since they're wrapping App that's why { children } is indicated? I'm not certain about this and I'd just like to know why things were done specifically like this (again, this is unlike what was demonstrated in past exercises). First post, thanks in advance.

**EDIT: After looking more into this issue I'm starting to come around and understand how they came up with this solution.** One of the few things they didn't do previously that was used in this example was the use of ({ children }). This caused confusion for me at first, but I've come closer to understanding its usage. For example, its use in the Paragraph component:

```
const Paragraph = ({ children }) => {
  const { theme } = useTheme();
  return (
    <p
      style={{
        color: theme === "light" ? "black" : "white",
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </p>
  );
};
```

Which is later referenced in the Content component as such:

```
<Paragraph>
        We are a pizza loving family. And for years, I searched and searched and
        searched for the perfect pizza dough recipe. I tried dozens, or more.
        And while some were good, none of them were that recipe that would
        make me stop trying all of the others.
</Paragraph>
```

This simply means to take the children of the Paragraph component and return the information styled as such. Whatever comes inside of Paragraph, in this case a block of text, was returned with the intended style. I thought of deleting this post but maybe it will help someone else. Not sure if adding more about what I learned here would be excessive, and I'm still wrapping my head around the rest of the issue so documenting here isn't my top priority as of now.

Answer (score 0):

React Context is a relatively new feature that the React team introduced to enable an alternative to holding state in a component and prop drilling. The context provider is a node that holds a value, which can be accessed by any node rendered under it (any `children` or `children` of `children`) via the `createContext()` with `useContext` or `Context.Consumer`. When the `value` of the Provider changes, any component subscribed with `useContext` or rendered by `Consumer` will be rerendered.

There is no practical difference between using the provider directly in `index.js`. What matters is who is rendered under the provider. Keep in mind that JSX's `<ThemeProvider>` is in reality a call to `React.createElement` with `App` in the `children` argument.

Why create a `ThemeProvider`? It packages the provider with state. The alternative would be to use the provider directly in `Root` and create `useState` there, but it is inflexible and not reusable.

```
const ThemeContext = createContext(undefined);

function Root() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("light");

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider
      value={{
        theme,
        toggleTheme: () => setTheme(theme === "light" ? "dark" : "light"),
      }}
    >
      <App />
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Note that `App` is still the `children` of the provider.

Comment: `React Context is a relatively new feature` Context existed [before version 1.0](https://reactjs.org/blog/2014/03/28/the-road-to-1.0.html). It's definitely had significant changes since then, but it's by no means new.

Comment: Interesting. I only knew of the public origin in https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html#official-context-api.